# How do I make a slippy map with a GeoTiff?

Tags: gdal, cartography, gdal2tiles, slippy

It seems that most applications I use for serving map data, gdal2tiles or Geoserver takes the supplied GeoTiffs and chops it up into png files with no metadata.  What is the standard practice to place these tiles correctly.  Do I just lose elevation and bounding box data and that's it?  Do I just place the tiles based off of the transform of the previous zoom level?  I feel like there is something fundamental I'm missing.

Comment: Did you try using a Web Coverage Service to serve your data which was already mentioned in a comment from your last question (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254107/does-gdal2tiles-strip-elevation-data#comment400465_254107)?

Comment: Geoserver does not serve the KML files.  gdal2tiles does.  I'm stuck with Geoserver and was wondering if I was missing something.

Comment: This is from GeoServer and it looks like KML http://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/nurc/wms/kml?layers=nurc:Img_Sample. That KML wants to read images from server, not from a directory of tiles but it is still KML.

Comment: I found a great video on WCS, its a little slow but very informative https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=--j8ZD0Zdf8

Answer (score 1):

It is not quite true that gdal2tiles does not create metadata. If you use the default profile then tiling schema is the one used by Google Maps and it is supposed to be well-know. If you run gdal2tiles with raster profile (-p raster) you will find file "tilemapresource.xml" which contains the necessary Tile Map Service metadata. Individual tiles do not have metadata and their georeferensing is interpreted by the metadata of the tiling schema. Tile map clients know how to reach each tile and where to place it on the map.

GeoServer is sending tiles through a service and users are supposed to know how to access the metadata from each service. Those requests are like

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wms?request=GetCapabilities&version=1.1.1&tiled=true

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetCapabilities

Live example about WMTS metadata

http://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetCapabilities

Save response on disk, it won't open into your browser.

I don't understand how elevation is related with tiling and metadata.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, it looks like WMTS will solve the bounding box issue.   Each pixel in the GEOTiff file I'm using has elevation data associated with it and I was wondering if there was a way to keep it intact.  I'll start looking into WMTS and WCS to see if there is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need.to use gdaldem assign color values to elevation ranges then run tiles.   You can also use JOERD python script by mapzen that create terrarium PNG format.take a look at geopackage elevation that probably your best bet